# Basic quadratic calculus

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Given $$ AX^2+2X-1=0 \,\ \text{where} \,\ A>0$$ 
What value of A would make the absolute value of both roots bigger than $1$?
I found the roots using quadratic formula and also found that A has to be both $[0,3]$ and $[-1,0]$ and $A>0$, does it mean such an $A$ doesn't exist? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Note: The original question stated "both roots are greater than 1", without any mention of absolute value.  This solution is for that question.**

If you're familiar with [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), then the product of the two roots will  be $\frac{-1}{A}$.  If both roots are greater than $1$, then their product is as well, so $\frac{-1}{A}>1$ and hence $A<-1$. However, the sum of the two roots will be $-\frac{2}{A}$.  Since $A<-1$, the sum of the two roots will be less than $-\frac{2}{-1}=2$.  But it's not possible for two numbers, each greater than $1$, to have sum less than $2$.

Comment: Thank you for introducing Vieta's formula, its new to me!

Answer (score 1):

**Note: The original question stated "both roots are greater than 1", without any mention of absolute value.  This solution is for that question.**

We want $$\frac{-2\pm \sqrt{4+4A}}{2A}=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+A}}{A}>1$$

If $A>0$ then $-1+\sqrt{1+A}>-1-\sqrt{1+A}$ so both roots are bigger than 1 if $$-1-\sqrt{1+A}>A$$
which rearranges to $$0>1+A+\sqrt{1+A}$$
This is plainly impossible, so no solutions exist for $A>0$.

If $A<0$ we must in fact have $-1\le A<0$ else we are taking an impossible square root.  Now $$\frac{-1-\sqrt{1+A}}{A}>\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+A}}{A}(>0)$$
so both roots are bigger than 1 if $$\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+A}}{A}>1$$
We multiply both sides by the negative $A$, getting $$-1+\sqrt{1+A}<A$$
which rearranges to $$\sqrt{1+A}<1+A$$
However $0\le A+1<1$, so $\sqrt{1+A}$ is never less than $1+A$.  Hence no solutions exist for $A<0$ either.

Comment: Sorry I edited before seeing your response, Thank you for your input tho I really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The roots are

$$ X_1=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+A}}{A},\;\;\; \text{and}\;\;\; X_2=\frac{-1-\sqrt{1+A}}{A}. $$

Notice that $X_2<0$ for any $A>0$. So there exists no $A$ such that both roots are positive.

Comment: And why  must $A$ be positive?

Comment: its given in the problem that A>0

Answer (score 0):

For $A>0$ we have
\begin{align}
0&=X^2 + 2 \frac{1}{A}X - \frac{1}{A} \\
&= (X + 1/A)^2 -1/A^2 -1/A \\
&=  (X - (-1/A))^2 + (- (A+1)/A^2) \iff \\
X &= \frac{\pm\sqrt{A+1}-1}{A}
\end{align}
This is a parabola with vertex at $(-1/A, -(A+1)/A^2)$.

Then
$$
\frac{\sqrt{A+1}-1}{A}
\le \lvert X\rvert 
= \left\lvert \frac{\pm\sqrt{A+1}-1}{A} \right\rvert
\le \frac{\sqrt{A+1}+1}{A}
$$
So we need
\begin{align}
1 &< \frac{\sqrt{A+1}-1}{A} \iff \\
A + 1 &< \sqrt{A+1} \Rightarrow \\
(A + 1)^2 &< A + 1 \iff \\
A^2 + 2A + 1 &< A+1 \iff \\
A^2 + A &< 0
\end{align}
This is not possible for positive $A$, as $A^2$ is positive as well.